# How to create a new core in solr using java code?

Tags: solr

I am new in solr and i want to create a new core in solr by using java code and i don't want create it by terminal and GUI of solr, this is code that i am using and i am using 6.2.1 version of solr,  please help me . thanx in advance.

```
           coreName="metademo";
          String solrDir = "/home/manish/Downloads/solr-6.2.1/server/solr/";

        String baseSolrUrl ="http://localhost:8983/solr/";
        CoreAdminRequest.Create create = new CoreAdminRequest.Create(); 
        create.setCoreName("metademo"); 
        create.setInstanceDir(solrDir +File.separator ); 
        SolrClient client2=new   HttpSolrClient.Builder(baseSolrUrl).build();

        create.setDataDir(solrDir + File.separator + coreName + File.separator + "data"); 
        HttpSolrServer solrServer1 = new HttpSolrServer(solrDir,client); 
        CoreAdminRequest.createCore(coreName, solrDir, client2);
        create.createCore(coreName, solrDir, client2);
        System.out.println("Created core with name: " + coreName);
```

Comment: What's the problem with this code?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you have to create the ***core folder*** in the ***solr directory*** (in your case: `/home/manish/Downloads/solr-6.2.1/server/solr/metademo`).

This folder has to have the same name that you'll use in your java code.

Then inside of this new core directory (in your case named "metademo") copy from `/.../solr-6.2.1/server/solr/configsets/basic_configs`, the so called `/conf` directory.

Once copied, inside the `/.../solr-6.2.1/server/solr/metademo/conf` folder, you have to change the name of `managed-schema` file in `schema.xml`.

I try this:

```
String coreName = "metademo";
String solrDir = "/.../solr-6.2.1/server/solr/metademo";
String baseSolrUrl = "http://localhost:8983/solr/";
SolrClient client = new HttpSolrClient(baseSolrUrl);
CoreAdminRequest.Create createRequest = new CoreAdminRequest.Create();
createRequest.setCoreName(coreName);
createRequest.setInstanceDir(solrDir);
createRequest.process(client);
```

and works. Without previous operation your code can only throw exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

The following code snippet works with Solr 8.5.2:

```
    String core = "test";
    CoreAdminRequest.Create createRequest = new CoreAdminRequest.Create();
    createRequest.setCoreName(core);
    createRequest.setInstanceDir("./" + core);
    createRequest.setConfigSet("_default");
    createRequest.process(solrClient);
```

The call to `setConfigSet()` is necessary, so that the server can know how to initialize configurations for the new core based on the specified configset. Otherwise, some exception message like "Unable to create core [test] Caused by: Can't find resource 'solrconfig.xml' in classpath" would be thrown.